# How can I break a path into two in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

1. I selected a node, and then clicked "break path at selected nodes."
2. Then I selected a node and hit ctrl-a to select all other nodes attached to it.  It jumped the gap I had just made.
3. I also tried going to the menu `Path > Break Apart`.  It did not separate the path at the break point.
4. I also tried `Path > Split Path`.  It did not separate the two chunks of path.

How can I take a path and split it at a vertex so it becomes two separate paths that can have separate colors and be moved separately?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I thought my path was a single line, but it was actually a full loop.

[image]

If this issue arises, make sure that you've used the "break path at selected nodes" button to break apart your path fully.  It may require two breaks if the path is a enclosed shape.  Then use `Path > Break Apart` to turn the two separate shapes into separate objects.